# Android Kotlin Room Repository unable to retrieve row from within detail activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, repository-pattern, kotlin-coroutines

I'm really struggling with this & would appreciate some help please. I'm learning **Android Kotlin** & building an app that displays a list of **walking routes** (downloaded from the cloud) in a **RecyclerView** &, when a route is selected I want to display all details of the route - a simple Master-Detail app. Since, I'm learning I also want to try and use best practice. I have most of it working fine using a Room database & a Repository. The database is correctly populated and the RecyclerView displays the list of routes. When a route is selected the `routeID` and other details are correctly passed to an activity `(TwalksRouteActivity.kt)` to display the details & this works fine.

However, I need to use the routeID to looks up the route from the database (Repository?) so all the details are available in the detail activity but I can't get this to work. I don't want to pass all of the details in a bundle because I will need to do other database look ups from the detail activity once this is working. I have tried all sorts of solutions around Coroutines to avoid thread blocking but have failed completely. So my question is, how do I correctly get a row from my database/repository from the detail activity.

Here's the detail activity (TwalksRouteActivity.kt):

```html
package com.example.android.twalks.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.android.twalks.R
import com.example.android.twalks.database.RouteDao
import com.example.android.twalks.database.getDatabase
import com.example.android.twalks.domain.Route
import com.example.android.twalks.repository.RoutesRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import timber.log.Timber
import timber.log.Timber.*

class TwalksRouteActivity() : AppCompatActivity()  {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var bundle: Bundle? = intent.extras
        var routeID = bundle?.getInt("routeID")
        var routeName = bundle?.getString("routeName")
        var routeCategoryName = bundle?.getString("routeCategoryName")
        var routeDistance = bundle?.getString("routeDistance")
        var routeTime = bundle?.getString("routeTime")
        var routeImageFile = bundle?.getString("routeImageFile")

        GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main) {
            val database = getDatabase(application)
            val routesRepository = RoutesRepository(database)
            val selectedRoute = routesRepository.getRoute(routeID)
            Log.d("CWM", selectedRoute.toString())

        }

        setContentView(R.layout.route_detail)

        val routeName_Text: TextView = findViewById(R.id.routeName_text)
        routeName_Text.text = routeName.toString()
        val routeID_Text: TextView = findViewById(R.id.routeID)
        routeID_Text.text = routeID.toString()

        //Toast.makeText(this,"Here in TwalksRouteActivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        //Toast.makeText(applicationContext,routeName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    }
}
```

DatabaseEntities.kt

```html
package com.example.android.twalks.database

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import com.example.android.twalks.domain.Route

/**
 * DataTransferObjects go in this file. These are responsible for parsing responses from the server
 * or formatting objects to send to the server. You should convert these to domain objects before
 * using them.
 */

@Entity
data class DatabaseRoute constructor(
        @PrimaryKey
        val routeID: String,
        val routeName: String,
        val routeImageFile: String,
        val routeCategoryName: String,
        val routeCategory: String,
        val routeDistance: String,
        val routeTime: String,
        val routeStatus:String)

fun List<DatabaseRoute>.asDomainModel(): List<Route> {
        return map {
                Route(
                        routeID = it.routeID,
                        routeName = it.routeName,
                        routeImageFile = it.routeImageFile,
                        routeCategoryName = it.routeCategoryName,
                        routeCategory = it.routeCategory,
                        routeDistance = it.routeDistance,
                        routeTime = it.routeTime,
                        routeStatus = it.routeStatus)
        }
}
```

Note that the GlobalScope block returns a kotlin.Unit in the log so no record is being returned. This is where I need help!

Room.kt

```html
package com.example.android.twalks.database

import android.content.Context
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*
import com.example.android.twalks.domain.Route

@Dao
interface RouteDao {
    @Query("select * from databaseroute")
    fun getRoutes(): LiveData<List<DatabaseRoute>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(vararg routes: DatabaseRoute)

    @Query("select * from databaseroute where routeID = :routeID")
    fun getRoute(routeID: Int?): LiveData<Route>
}

@Database(entities = [DatabaseRoute::class],version = 1)
abstract class RoutesDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val routeDao: RouteDao
}

private lateinit var INSTANCE: RoutesDatabase

fun getDatabase(context: Context): RoutesDatabase {
    synchronized(RoutesDatabase::class.java) {
        if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                    RoutesDatabase::class.java,
                    "routes").build()
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE
}
```

Models.kt (Domain Object):

```html
package com.example.android.twalks.domain

/**
 * Domain objects are plain Kotlin data classes that represent the things in our app. These are the
 * objects that should be displayed on screen, or manipulated by the app.
 *
 * @see database for objects that are mapped to the database
 * @see network for objects that parse or prepare network calls
 */

data class Route(val routeID: String,
                 val routeName: String,
                 val routeImageFile: String,
                 val routeCategoryName: String,
                 val routeCategory: String,
                 val routeDistance: String,
                 val routeTime: String,
                 val routeStatus: String)
```

DataTransferObjects.kt:

```html
package com.example.android.twalks.network

import android.os.Parcelable
import com.example.android.twalks.database.DatabaseRoute
import com.example.android.twalks.domain.Route
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class NetworkRouteContainer(val routes: List<NetworkRoute>)


@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class NetworkRoute(
        val routeID: String,
        val routeName: String,
        val routeImageFile: String,
        val routeCategoryName: String,
        val routeCategory: String,
        val routeDistance: String,
        val routeTime: String,
        val routeStatus: String )
/**
 * Convert Network results to com.example.android.twalks.database objects
 */

fun NetworkRouteContainer.asDomainModel(): List<Route> {
    return routes.map {
        Route(
                routeID = it.routeID,
                routeName = it.routeName,
                routeImageFile = it.routeImageFile,
                routeCategoryName = it.routeCategoryName,
                routeCategory = it.routeCategory,
                routeDistance = it.routeDistance,
                routeTime = it.routeTime,
                routeStatus = it.routeStatus)
    }
}

fun NetworkRouteContainer.asDatabaseModel(): Array<DatabaseRoute> {
    return routes.map {
        DatabaseRoute(
                routeID = it.routeID,
                routeName = it.routeName,
                routeImageFile = it.routeImageFile,
                routeCategoryName = it.routeCategoryName,
                routeCategory = it.routeCategory,
                routeDistance = it.routeDistance,
                routeTime = it.routeTime,
                routeStatus = it.routeStatus
        )
    }.toTypedArray()
}
```

RoutesRepository:

```html
package com.example.android.twalks.repository

import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.WorkerThread
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations
import com.example.android.twalks.database.RouteDao
import com.example.android.twalks.database.RoutesDatabase
import com.example.android.twalks.database.asDomainModel

import com.example.android.twalks.domain.Route
import com.example.android.twalks.network.Network
import com.example.android.twalks.network.asDatabaseModel


import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import timber.log.Timber

/**
 * Repository for fetching routes from the network and storing them on disk
 */
class RoutesRepository(private val database: RoutesDatabase) {

    val routes: LiveData<List<Route>> =
            Transformations.map(database.routeDao.getRoutes()) {
                it.asDomainModel()
            }

    suspend fun refreshRoutes() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val routelist = Network.twalks.getRoutes().await()
            database.routeDao.insertAll(*routelist.asDatabaseModel())
                    }
    }

    suspend fun getRoute(id: Int?) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val route: LiveData<Route> = database.routeDao.getRoute(id)
            //Log.d("CWM2",route.toString())
            return@withContext route
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you're not returning anything from `getRoute` in your `RoutesRepository` class. Specify the return type and you'll see it.

You can solve it by returning the `withContext` block, but I'd like to suggest you some changes since you said you're learning and also want to try and apply best practices.

### RouteDao

Room supports coroutines since version 2.1. All you have to do is marking your DAO methods with the keyword `suspend`. You don't have to worry about calling a `suspend` DAO method on your Main thread since it gets suspended and Room manages to execute the query on a background thread.

- Learn more about this subject [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5).

So your `getRoute` DAO method would look like this:

```
@Query("select * from databaseroute where routeID = :routeID")
suspend fun getRoute(routeID: Int): Route
```

**Note 1:** I changed the return type from `LiveData<Route>` to `Route` since I assume you don't expect it to change.

**Note 2:** I don't see the point in having a nullable `routeID` as argument so I removed the `?`.

---

### RoutesRepository

With the previous change your `getRoute` method on your `RoutesRepository` class would look like this:

```
suspend fun getRoute(id: Int) = database.routeDao.getRoute(id)
```

**Note 1:** As I mentioned before, you don't have to worry about moving to a background thread since Room will do it for you.

**Note 2:** Again, not nullable argument.

---

### TwalksRouteActivity

You're calling your repository directly from your activity. I'm not sure about the architecture you're applying but I would expect to see a Presenter or a ViewModel in the middle. Omitting that detail, I suggest you to avoid starting a coroutine with `GlobalScope` almost always. Use `GlobalScope` only when you know how `GlobalScope` works and you're totally sure about what you're doing.

- Learn more about this subject [here](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc).

Instead of `GlobalScope` you can use `lifecycleScope` which runs on the main thread and it's lifecycle aware.

Change your `GlobalScope.launch {...}` to this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    ...
    val selectedRoute = routesRepository.getRoute(routeID)
    //Do something with selectedRoute here
}
```

**Note 1:** You need `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0` or higher.

**Note 2:** If you're getting all the Route data in your request, you could pass only its `routeID` to your new activity.

Comment: Thank you so much Glenn, your answer worked perfectly, was clear, and your explanation really helped me understand what is going on :-)